# How to set up MouseButton4 on TeamSpeak

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, mouse, teamspeak

Is there a way to set up Button4/5 to push-to-talk in TeamSpeak?

For Example: In Firefox I can undoing and forwarding but 
TeamSpeak doesn't recognize clicks.

I'm using Arch Linux and my mouse is SteelSeries Rival.

EDIT:

```
[malloc@arch ~]$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Rival Gaming Mouse            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries Rival Gaming Mouse            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SteelSeries Rival Gaming Mouse            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[malloc@arch ~]$ xinput get-button-map 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
[malloc@arch ~]$ xinput get-button-map 13
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Do you need to map button 4 so it behaves like a different button, or like a key?

Comment: no matter how..

Comment: How dos "push-to-talk in TeamSpeak" work normally? Do you need to press some special key, or a specific mouse button?

Comment: I don't understand you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not very clear because I do not know teamspeak - but I think you may need to remap some mouse buttons. If that's what you need, I can tell you how.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPyDjxdKSO4   in linux teamspeak is the same. Mouse left, right and scroll button works fine. problem is with mouse4,5

Comment: When I run `xinput test 11` and press that buttons, button were called 8 and 9

Comment: You could try `xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 8 9 6 7 4 5"`

Comment: not work for me. Mouse 1 is left, 2 is right, 3 is scroll, 4 is scroll up, 5 is scroll down. when I try u command, In scroll up I can undoing changes, but teamspeak still not recognize buttons

Comment: Are you sure it's possible? Looking around, I saw it was not possible a while ago to use more than Button 1-3 under linux. Not implemented, and not plan to implement (but that was 2008 or so)

Comment: Everything is possible, that button works, but not in TS. maybe some script with binds?

Comment: Ok, so we can assume it's not possible to use the mouse buttons directly. Would it help to map the mouse buttons to hotkeys?

Comment: We can try. maybe F8 ?

Comment: It's not that easy to map a mouse button to a hotkey, because you do not want to map it in all windows, only in one. So the mapping program needs to detect an match the window. It could be done with `easystroke` or `imwheel`, for example.

Comment: (`imwheel` can be hard to configure to match the right window)